# Why am I getting the following error "the content of element type listener must match (listener)*"?

Tags: selenium, junit, testng, testng-eclipse

I was trying to implement IAnnotationTransformer interface of TestNG to retry failed Test Cases again but am getting the following error in my TestNG.xml

[Screenshot of the error being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG4GU.jpg)

**Code for MyTransformer** :

```
package Analyzer;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class MyTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer{

public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstrustor, Method testMethod) {
    annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(RetryAnalyzer.class);
}

}
```

**Code for RetryAnalyzer Class**:

```
package Analyzer;

import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer{
    int counter = 0;
    int retryLimit = 3;
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(counter < retryLimit) {
            counter++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Could anyone explain why I am getting this error and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you have blocked the code in error message:

it has to follow this pattern

```
<listeners>
   <listener class-name="your listener class"></listener>
</listeners>
```

hope this heps

Comment: Hi, sorry didn't notice that i have hidden the code but FYI I have done the same.